# SQL Sub query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to catch Sub Query output on where

There is my SQL code

```
SELECT Txn.TrnID, Txn.Date, Txn.Amount,
(SELECT `MetaValue` FROM `meta` WHERE `Parent` = 'DB_Transaction' AND `MainID` = Txn.TrnID AND `MetaKey` = 'SalesID' AND `MetaValue` = '803') AS SubqueryResult
FROM transaction as Txn
WHERE SubqueryResult = '803'
LIMIT 10
```

I'm getting this error

> Unknown column 'SubqueryResult' in 'where clause'

Comment: That is invalid query.

Comment: does the subquery execute correctly?

Comment: try this: SELECT Txn.TrnID, Txn.Date, Txn.Amount,
m.MetaValue
FROM transaction as Txn
inner join meta as m 
   on m.Parent = 'DB_Transaction'
   and m.MainID = Txn.TrnID 
   AND m.MetaKey = 'SalesID' 
   AND m.MetaValue = '803'
LIMIT 10

Comment: You are correct Dr.Stitch.
If you post this answer i can approve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you can try  Dr. Stitch. which is

```
SELECT Txn.TrnID, Txn.Date, Txn.Amount, m.MetaValue FROM transaction as Txn inner join meta as m    on m.Parent = 'DB_Transaction' and m.MainID = Txn.TrnID AND m.MetaKey = 'SalesID' AND m.MetaValue = '803' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an error in the query. You can not use `AS valueName` of subquery result in where clause. Because that name will be assigned after executing the whole query. So in `where` clause it will not find `SubqueryResult` column in your case.

**What you can do is:(Use Original Column name in Where clause)**

```
SELECT Txn.TrnID, Txn.Date, Txn.Amount,
(SELECT `MetaValue` FROM `meta` WHERE `Parent` = 'DB_Transaction' AND `MainID` = Txn.TrnID AND `MetaKey` = 'SalesID' AND `MetaValue` = '803') AS SubqueryResult
FROM transaction as Txn
WHERE MetaValue = '803'
LIMIT 10
```